# Optimizing disk space for MyISAM tables: what is the benefit of ALTER and ANALYZE if you already do OPTIMIZE?

Tags: mysql, myisam, disk-space

Per [this post](https://serverfault.com/a/246111/57273), in order to optimize the storage of a MyISAM table, you need to:

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE ;
ALTER TABLE ENGINE=MyISAM ; 
ANALYZE TABLE ;
```

It's obvious what OPTIMIZE does for disk space but what does ALTER and ANALYZE do when used after OPTIMIZE? I am asking specifically about *disk storage*, so for example, I don't care that ANALYZE improves join performance, etc.

Comment: Thank you for catching the typo in my ServerFault post. +1 !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was my [old ServerFault post from two years ago](https://serverfault.com/questions/155455/how-do-myisam-and-innodb-utilize-hd-space/246111#246111). Forgive me, it is slightly misworded. It should read:

> As for MyISAM, you need to periodically run one of the following:
>
> - OPTIMIZE TABLE `myisam-tablename`;
> - ALTER TABLE `myisam-tablename` ENGINE=MyISAM; ANALYZE TABLE `myisam-tablename`;

OK, I just fixed it in ServerFault.

## CLARIFICATION

`OPTIMIZE TABLE tblname;` performs the following:

```
ALTER TABLE ENGINE=MyISAM tblname; 
ANALYZE TABLE tblname;
```

According to the [**MySQL Documentation on `OPTIMIZE TABLE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html)

> For MyISAM tables, `OPTIMIZE TABLE` works as follows:
>
> ```
>  If the table has deleted or split rows, repair the table.
>
>  If the index pages are not sorted, sort them.
>
>  If the table's statistics are not up to date
> (and the repair could not be accomplished by sorting the index), update them.
> ```

The last part on the table's statistics is what `ANALYZE TABLE` does.

If you do not want `OPTIMIZE TABLE tblname;` to perform `ANALYZE TABLE tblname;`, then you must execute `ALTER TABLE tblname ENGINE=MyISAM;` instead.

**WARNING** : This may not be a good idea for a MyISAM that has heavy INSERTs, UPDATEs, and DELETEs because

- This will make table and index statistics stale very quickly
- Stale statistics will cause the Query Optimizer to make bad choices for query EXPLAIN plans

Please just stick with `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.